# Inserting products to subschema taking long time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have mongoose schema:

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
    "productId"         : {type : String},
    "productName"       : {type : String},
    "mrp"               : {type : String}

});

var shopSchema = new Schema({
    "ShopId"    : {type : Number},
    "Name"      : {type : String},
    "contact"   : {type : Number},
    "products"  : [productSchema]
},{collection:"shopProductDetails"});

module.exports.Shops    = mongoose.model('Shops',shopSchema);
module.exports.Products = mongoose.model('Products',productSchema);
```

I inserted data into the shop successfully .Next I have to **insert data** into the sub schema that is **productSchema**

**Insertion Data**

```
{
  "ShopId":"439",
    "products": [{
  "productId": "1234",
  "productName": "non veg",
  "mrp": "38",
  }, {
  "productId": "5678",
  "productName": "veg",
  "mrp": "38 "
  },{...}]
 }
```

**Products Insertion Code:**

```
 model.Shops.findOne({"ShopId":439},function(err, doc){
    if(doc == null){
      res.json({'success':'0','result':{},'errorMessage':'Credentials not matched'});
    }
    else{
       async.each(products,function(item){
        var insertProducts={productId: item.productId, productName: item.productName, mrp: item.mrp};
        doc.products.push(insertProducts)
        });
        doc.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
              res.json({'errorMessage':err});
             }
         else {
           res.json({'success':'1','result':{'message':'Products Inserted Successfully'},'errorMessage':'No'});
         }
       });
   }
});
```

**Here the products are inserted successfully, the problem is that it is taking a large time when there is a bulk data. I am using async here,i think its wrong.Can any one suggest a better approach**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you only having the reference id for the product in the shop. It will save you time when making the query (now you just have to insert an id instead of looking up for another document in the database).

Comment: There is mongo id , i just removed it  from the code for posting the question here.